# Generalising a "next permutation" function

Tags: scala, types, generics, permutation

Below is an implementation of a function that returns the lexographically next permutation. This is useful in one of the Euler problems.

It's written to work on Strings (which I needed for that). However, it should work on any indexed sequence of comparable values. I've tried generalising it by changing the two occurrences of String to IndexedSeq[Char], but this gets an error:

```
euler-lib.scala:26: error: type mismatch;
 found   : IndexedSeq[Char]
 required: String
      ((n.slice(pivot+1, successor):+ n(pivot)) + n.drop(successor+1)).reverse
                                                        ^
```

Why has the type inferencer inferred String there? I don't seem to have done any operation that requires a String?

And can I make it more general still by having IndexedSeq["something-comparable"]? I've not been able to make this work.

```
  // return the lexographically next permutation to the one passed as a parameter
  // pseudo-code from an article on StackOverflow
  def nextPermutation(n:String):String = {
  // 1. scan the array from right-to-left
  //1.1. if the current element is less than its right-hand neighbor,
  //    call the current element the pivot,
  //    and stop scanning
  // (We scan left-to-right and return the last such).
    val pivot = n.zip(n.tail).lastIndexWhere{ case (first, second) => first < second }

  //1.2. if the left end is reached without finding a pivot,
  //    reverse the array and return
  //    (the permutation was the lexicographically last, so its time to start over)
    if (pivot < 0) return n.reverse

  //2. scan the array from right-to-left again,
  //   to find the rightmost element larger than the pivot
  //  (call that one the successor)
    val successor = n.lastIndexWhere{_ > n(pivot)}

  //3. swap the pivot and the successor, and
  //4. reverse the portion of the array to the right of where the pivot was found
    return (n.take(pivot) :+ n(successor)) +
      ((n.slice(pivot+1, successor):+ n(pivot)) + n.drop(successor+1)).reverse
  }
```

Comment: The C version, de-generalized `int` version: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/256255/126584

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `+` in `IndexedSeq` is used to produce a new sequence containing one additional given element but you want to produce one containing an additional sequence. The method for this is `++` thus your last line must look like this:

```
(n.take(pivot) :+ n(successor)) ++
  ((n.slice(pivot+1, successor):+ n(pivot)) ++ n.drop(successor+1)).reverse
```

You are seeing this strange compiler message about a `String` being expected because `+`'s signature does not match and thus an explicit conversion used for String concatenation kicks in (this conversion is there because it lets you write something like `List(8) + " Test"`).

**EDIT:** Generalization over sequence types of ordered elements:

As I said in the comments, generalization over sequences is a bit more complicated. In addition to your element type `A` you will need another type `CC[X] <: SeqLike[X,CC[X]]` that represents the sequence. Normally `C <: SeqLike[A,C]` would be sufficient but the type inferencer does not like that one (you would always need to pass the types of `A` and `C` when calling that method).

If you just change your signature that way the compiler will complain that it requires an implicit `CanBuildFrom[CC[A],A,CC[A]]` parameter as that one is needed e.g. by the `reverse` method. That parameter is used to build one sequence type from another one - just search the site to see some examples of how it is used by the collections API.

The final result would look like this:

```
import collection.SeqLike
import collection.generic.CanBuildFrom

def nextPermutation[A, CC[X] <: SeqLike[X,CC[X]]](n: CC[A])(
  implicit ord: Ordering[A], bf: CanBuildFrom[CC[A],A,CC[A]]): CC[A] = {

  import ord._
  // call toSeq to avoid having to require an implicit CanBuildFrom for (A,A)
  val pivot = n.toSeq.zip(n.tail.toSeq).lastIndexWhere{
    case (first, second) => first < second
  }

  if (pivot < 0) {
    n.reverse
  }
  else {
    val successor = n.lastIndexWhere{_ > n(pivot)}
    (n.take(pivot) :+ n(successor)) ++
    ((n.slice(pivot+1, successor):+ n(pivot)) ++ n.drop(successor+1)).reverse
  }
}
```

This way you get a `Vector[Int]` if you passed one to the method and a `List[Double]` if you passed that to the method. So what about `String`s? Those are not actual sequences but they can be implicitly converted into a `Seq[Char]`. It is possible alter the definition of that method expect some type that can be implicitly converted into a `Seq[A]` but then again type inference would not work reliably - or at least I could not make it work reliably. As a simple workaround you could define an additional method for `String`s:

```
def nextPermutation(s: String): String =
  nextPermutation[Char,Seq](s.toSeq).mkString
```

Comment: Thanks. Why does my original work then? (when used with Strings) if I've got the element/sequence confused? And can I make it work over indexed-sequence of anything-comparable? Also, when I change it tow use IndexSeq[Char], and I call it with a String "1463", I get a Vector(1,6,3,4) back, rather than a String?

Comment: Because you can concatenate Strings using `+`. It would be more consistent if you would have to use `++` for that too but I think it was a decision to keep it consistent with Java (see the example).As for your additional questions: [for comparable values it can be done easily](https://gist.github.com/716746) but generalizing on collection types is a bit harder (but also possible).

Comment: Can you give me some pointers about generalizing over collection types? Also I still have that pesky Vector return - how do I make it return the type passed in?

Comment: Updated the answer to also include that.

Comment: Thanks. I think I need some quiet time and an icepack for an overheated brain before I understand the nuances, but I appreciate the time and effort you've put into explaining it.

Comment: For a straightforward example of parameterizing the collection type, see Random#shuffle.   https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/util/Random.scala#L108  ... which will even shuffle an Iterator, amusingly enough.

Answer (score 1):

Little tip here:

```
n(pivot)) + n.drop(successor+1)
                  ^
```

When you get a type mismatch error, and the `^` points to the first parenthesis of the last argument list (ie, it would point to the second `(` in `x.foldLeft(y)(z)`), that means the value returned *by that method* has the wrong type.

Or, in this case, `n.drop(sucessor+1)` has type `IndexedSeq[Char]`, but the `+` method expects a `String`.

Another little tip: the only things that accept `+` are the numeric classes and `String`. If you try to add things and get an error, most likely it is Scala thinking you are using `+` to add `Strings`. For example:

```
true + true // expected String, got Boolean error
"true" + true // works, the second true is converted to String
true + "true" // works, the first true is converted to String
```

So, avoid `+` unless you are working with numbers or strings.

So, about making that general...

```
def nextPermutation[A <% Ordered[A]](n: IndexedSeq[A]): IndexedSeq[A] = {
  val pivot = n.zip(n.tail).lastIndexWhere{ case (first, second) => first < second }
  if (pivot < 0) return n.reverse
  val successor = n.lastIndexWhere{_ > n(pivot)}
  return (n.take(pivot) :+ n(successor)) ++
    ((n.slice(pivot+1, successor):+ n(pivot)) ++ n.drop(successor+1)).reverse
}
```

The easy part is just declaring `IndexedSeq`. But you have to parameterize on `A`, and there must be a way to order `A` so that you can compare the elements (`<%` means there's an implicit conversion from `A` to an `Ordered[A]` available). Another way to declare it would be like this:

```
def nextPermutation[A : Ordering](n: IndexedSeq[A]): IndexedSeq[A] = {
  val ordering = implicitly[Ordering[A]]; import ordering._
  val pivot = n.zip(n.tail).lastIndexWhere{ case (first, second) => first < second }
  if (pivot < 0) return n.reverse
  val successor = n.lastIndexWhere{_ > n(pivot)}
  return (n.take(pivot) :+ n(successor)) ++
    ((n.slice(pivot+1, successor):+ n(pivot)) ++ n.drop(successor+1)).reverse
}
```

Here, `A : Ordering` means there is an implicit `Ordering[A]` available, which is then obtained and imported into scope, so that it can offer implicit conversions to make `<` work. The difference between an `Ordered[A]` and an `Ordering[A]` can be found on other questions.

Answer (score 1):

Problem 24 had me stumped for a while:

```
println("0123456789".permutations.drop(1000000 - 1).next);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code compiles correclty for me in Scala 2.8.0.  Which version of Scala are you using ?

```
scala> nextPermutation("12354")
res0: String = 12435
```

Comment: Yes, it compiles correctly and works :) it doesn't compile if you replace the two occurrences of String with IndexedSeq[Char], though, which was (one of) my questions.